# can not display the contents of a database from cloud sql

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

i try to show my database content in my app at GAE.

and this is my connection.php

when i'm deploy to GAE :

```
[
session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect("dbrep","dbuser","dbpass");

//$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");

$select = mysql_select_db("db_repository");
]
```

when use LOCALHOST :

```
[
session_start();

//$connect = mysql_connect("dbrep","dbuser","dbpass");

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");

$select = mysql_select_db("db_repository");
]
```

i was import my database to google Cloud SQL, after im export it from localhost/phpmyadmin.

but at my app in GAE, i cant see the content in sidebar list etc.
anyone can help me how to solve my problem, thanks before :D

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Connect_to_your_database).
You'd want to use `':/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>'` instead of 'dbprep'.

Comment: I've tried to use it but still doesnt work, there is another way to solve this?

Comment: Does your cloud SQL actually have user "dbuser" and password "dbpass"? Also can you please update your question to show the exact code you are currenlty using? Also, does the connection code work or not? It seems you post connection code but then your error is that your cloudSQL doesn't appear in your developer console?